# Is there a way to reset the USB bulk endpoints using the Android USB host APIs

Tags: android, usb

I noticed that the UsbEndpoint class of the Android USB host API does not provide a method to reset the USB endpoints! 
I'm aware that I could send a CLEAR_FEATURE control transfer request to rest the endpoint on the device side but this request also resets the data toggle bit on the device side and results in the data toggle bit of the host controller side and device side get out of sync.

I'm looking for a function that reset the endpoint and clears the data toggle bit on both sides like the functions that Mac OS and Windows provide with their USB API. (Mac OS provides the ClearPipeStall and ClearPipeStallBothEnds functions and the ResetPipe function is available on windows for this purpose)

Comment: have you tried to call the function releaseInterface(UsbInterface intf) to release the endpoint's interface??? it may solve your problem.. plz do feedback...